# Clean URL using .htaccess in PHP pages

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi i have a site called `finittra.com` all menu's are dynamically linked with the page. I tried to make the site as like as a CMS. If i click on the about menu the url shows that http://www.finittra.com/?page=about & if i click on the contact page the url shows site `url /?page=contact` but i want that i would like to show everything within  the `finittra.com/finittra/` as like as a folder or canonical link type which is search engine optimization url friendly.  Please anybody here to help me?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to rewrite your URLs using .htaccess. You can use this mod-rewrite generator: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite

Example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?page=$1 [L]
```

But a proper & organized way would be using a Router, try [Aura.Router](https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Router)

Example usage:

```
$routes = [
    [
        "name"    => "My_route",
        "pattern" => "/{page}",
    ],
    [
        "name"    => "Another_route",
        "pattern" => "/pages/{page}",
    ]
];
```

This is your routes array, the router will go through all routes and check if the given request url matches any of them.

```
$factory = new RouterFactory;
$router = $factory->newInstance();

foreach ($routes as $route) {
    $router->add($route['name'], $route['pattern']);
}

$path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);

$match = $router->match($path, $_SERVER);
if ($match) {
    $params = $match->params;
    echo $params['page'];
}
```

URL to echo the page param: http://www.finittra.com/about

You will need to do the same as get for POST requests, but instead u'll need to add them manually to the url path. Atleast how I do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This rewrites every `finittra.com/xyz/` (which will be visible) to `finittra.com/?page=xyz`.
If you want your pages to have different names, you'll have to do that manually, I guess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^finittra/?$ index.php?page=contact [L,NC,QSA]
```

Also, you have to adjust the links on your website

Answer (score 0):

you must use .htaccess file in your project ,like :

.htaccess :

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks  
    RewriteEngine On  

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  


   RewriteRule ^user/(\d+)*$ ./page.php?id=$1
```

If url request equl : http://www.finittra.com/user/123

Load :page.php?id=123